# g is a Lipschitz on the interval [α-A,α+A] for some A>0. Prove |g'(α)|≤λ

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Suppose that g is a C1 function such that the Lipschitz estimate
**|g(x)-g(y)|≤λ|x-y|** holds an interval **[α-A,α+A]** for some **A>0**. Prove that **|g'(α)|≤λ**. (Hint: consider the difference quotients used to define g'(α).)

Comment: the hint is already pretty much the proof...

Answer (score 1):

hint: $$g'(\alpha) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(\alpha + h) - g(\alpha)}{h}$$
Can we manipulate this into something more useful?